How to tackle this optimization with binary variables?
So, I have a (practical) optimization problem in which (somewhat large, say $1500$) $N$ binary variables need to be found.
$
\min_{a \in \{0,1\} ^N} \sum_i \left(\frac{a_i w_i}{\sum_j a_j w_j}\right)^2 \text{s.t.} \sum_k a_k \ge 1
$
where all given $w_i \in (0,1)$
$2^{1500}$ is a rather large number, so I hope brute force is not the only approach. Then again, I do require a really optimal solution, not "the hope" of a best solution.
Is there a (perhaps well-known) algorithm that could be applied here?

The only constraint you have in your model restricts you to choosing at least 1 element. Given that, you can consider without loss of generality only the solutions with $x_1 = 1$ in the sense that if you can solve that sub-problem, you can lift it to solving the original problem by applying this solution to $x_1 = 1$, then to the $x_2 = 1$ subproblem, and so on until the $x_n = 1$ subproblem. The advantage of doing so is that you now have an unconstrained problem over binary variables.
Given that, you can now restate your problem as the 0—1 integer fractional programming model. (I also want to point out that Section 4 of the linked paper describes the exact solving methods.) First, let's "normalize" the objective:
$$\sum_i \left( \frac{w_i a_i}{\sum_j a_j w_j} \right)^2 = \frac{\sum_i w_i^2 a_i}{\sum_{i,j} w_i w_j a_i a_j} = \frac{w_1^2 + \sum_{i=2}^N w_i^2 a_i}{w_1^2 +\sum_{i=2}^N w_i^2 a_i+\sum_{i,j=2}^N w_i w_j a_i a_j}, $$
where I use the $a_j^2 = a_j$ identity, which holds since your variables are binary. Let's say you now apply the parametrization technique (Section 4.2). In that case, your problem will boil down to solving a collection of problems $$\phi(t)=\min \left\{ (1-t)w_1^2 + (1-t)\sum_{i=2}^N w_i^2 a_i - t \sum_{i,j=2}^N w_i w_j a_i a_j : a_i \in \{ 0, 1 \}, 2 \le i \le N \right\},$$ updating the parameter $t$ by Newton's method, and repeating doing so until you find $t^*$ such that $\phi(t^*) = 0$, which will yield you the optimal solution value. Each of $\phi(t)$ problems is an instance of quadratic unconstrained binary optimization which is, while still NP-hard, should be manageable for your problem size; as for solving that problem, you can either linearize it and feed to a MILP solver or use a tailored software package (e.g., QUBO.jl).
Edit: on second thought, you can also reverse the order of these two paragraphs, namely, start with introducing $\phi(t)$ on your original problem (but still applying the $a_i^2=a_i$ trick) and then decompose the resulting model in into $N$ QUBOs, one per each $x_i = 1$ assumption.
